# Why does taking a heap histo using OnOutOfMemoryError hang?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jmap, java-18

When the JVM (OpenJDK 18) throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, I want to make sure it stops and we take a heap histogram using `jmap`.

I achieve that with the flags `-XX:-ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/bin/jmap -histo:live $jpid && kill $jpid &`<sup>2</sup>. Assume that `$jpid` is the Java process's PID.

If I run `/usr/bin/jmap -histo:live $jpid && kill $jpid` (ie. without `&` at the end), `jmap` hangs indefinitely.

I wonder, why does `jmap` hang when I don't fork it (using `&`)?

---

<sub>1. I initially used `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` and `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/bin/jmap -histo:live $jpid`. That doesn't work, as the former flag will result in the JVM already being stopped when `jmap` is called.</sub>

<sub>2. In reality, the `jmap` + `kill` call is wrapped in a very simple shell script that logs some additional lines, but I omitted that for simplicity here.</sub>

Comment: I don't think it is hanging, it's just not running the process in the background because you removed the instruction to do so by removing the `&`. So it will exit, when the program ends. I believe that sharing more of the script will help here to understand the context.

Comment: `jmap` communicates with the JVM to create the heap dump. So it’s plausible that it will hang if you let the JVM wait for the completion of `jmap`.